# Quick jQuery question: Stopping event propagation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a set of elements that respond to mouseUp events, and inside of them are child elements that respond to mouseUp events as well (all via. jQuery).  How do I make it so when a child's mouseUp event occurs from a user mouse click the child's parent's mouseUp event doesn't also occur in jQuery?

Comment: I'm sorry, I had to vote this down. You can't even legitimately claim laziness since finding this via google or the jQuery doc site would take about half the time it took you to write this question.

Comment: Meh.  Now it's available here too. :P

Comment: +1 to counter Peter Bailey. It's SO's fault if it couldn't bring up a relevant question when the OP wrote his title. If it DID bring up a relevant question that's identical, it's STILL SO's fault for not making it prominent enough.

Comment: @Peter: when do you think it is justified to ask a question on SO?  You seem to think that it's somehow unethical to ask a question when you're capable of finding the answer yourself, and like the questioners are personally infringing on your rights.  

Most of us believe it's useful to build up questions and answers in one place, since the quality of material here on SO is much higher than just about anywhere else.  My opinion is that if the question doesn't already exist here, it's helping everyone to ask it.  If you think differently, please explain why...

Comment: @Brandon - I'd probably need something roughly the size of a blog post to go into the level of detail that would treat this topic fairly. But to sum up: lack of due diligence, documentation duplication, blatant RTFM, and inevitable obsolescence. And, if you ever listened to the SO podcast (particularly earlier ones) you will find that much of my viewpoint on this issue has been directly adopted from Joel and Jeff.  And please don't try to interpret my (or anyone else's, really) feelings from just a few lines of black and white. I don't feel personally infringed *in the slightest*

Comment: @Peter:  Almost every question on SO--or at least a very large percentage of them--could be answered by saying RTFM or JFGI.  Is there really anything that is on SO that is not available somewhere else by Googling? I doubt it.  The whole "RTFM/JFGI" attitude is not helpful.

Comment: @Peter: By saying "lack of due diligence" you're suggesting that SO ought to be a resource of last resort, AFTER someone has tried their best to figure it out on their own--as if they're wasting your time and being irresponsible by asking before doing their "due diligence". 

If we make it a resource of FIRST resort, then it becomes that much more useful for all of us.

Comment: @Brandon - I agree with your perspective, I just don't feel it applies to this particular question.  I think my *own* volume of answers shows that I believe in answering questions here on SO.  But in this instance, we'll just have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @Peter Bailey, this question is now first in Google. Where is your God now? Besides, JFGI is not a valid reason to close any question on SO.

Comment: @HeavyWave - Wow, you people are *so eager* for me to be wrong, aren't you? Regardless of how well SO's sitemap.xml optimizies this question into the google serp, I stand by my opinion for this question, because it's *my opinion*.  Besides, googling for "jquery stopping event propagation" gives me this as #1 http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want [event.stopPropagation()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.stopPropagation.28.29)

Comment: Okay thanks.  I'm just plowing through code here ATM so I'm getting lazy about looking stuff up in the docs. :P

Comment: For that, you'll want Google.doSearch(…) :)

Comment: I did a Google search and ended up here. So i'm happy to have the answer here, regardless where else it could be found.